# What caused the memory leak in this code?

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, stl, iterator

I am inspecting the code that may cause memory leak. I know something is wrong with std::set.erase(this) and the destructor of SomeObject. So how to fix it?

```
class SomeObject;
////....
std::set<SomeObject*> managedObjects;
///.....
class SomeObject{
public:
    SomeObject(){  managedObjects.insert(this); }
    SomeObject(SomeObject&& S)/*move cter*/{ managedObjects.insert(this); }
    virtual ~SomeObject() { managedObjects.erase(this); }
    ////....
};
////....
void clearAllObjects() {
    for(auto p : managedObjects){
        if(p){
            delete p;
        }
    }
    managedObjects.clear();
}
////....
```

Comment: `clearAllObjects` iterates over collection which changed on every iteration. Looks like UB. `delete p` -> `~SomeObject` -> `managedObjects.erase`

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @TedLyngmo The destructor for SomeObject calls erase on the set with every delete in the loop. Might cause some problems.

Comment: @Pzc Yeah, you are correct. I missed that part. The range based for-loop's internal iterator will get invalidated by that `erase`.

Comment: ... or is the internal iterator really invalidated? It feels like it _could_ be handled by the range based for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `delete` inside `clearAllObjects()` it will result in `managedObjects.erase(this)` which is the same as `managedObjects.erase(p)`.

This means that the internal iterator in the range based for-loop *may* be invalidated (I'm not sure). If it is, it'll try to do `++internal_iterator;` on an invalid iterator - with undefined behavior as a result.

To be safe, you could copy the iterator and step that to the next in the `set` before doing `erase`.

Also note: There's no need to check if what you `delete` is a nullptr or not. It's mandated by the standard to have no effect if that's the case.

Example:

```
void clearAllObjects() {
    for(auto pit = managedObjects.begin(); pit != managedObjects.end();) {
        delete *pit++ // postfix ++ returns a copy of the old iterator
    }
    
    managedObjects.clear();
}
```

A side effect by having this `managedObjects` `set` is that you can't have automatic variables of `SomeObject`.

```
int main() {
    SomeObject foo;
    clearAllObjects(); // deletes the automatic object "foo" (not allowed)
}                      // <- the automatic object is destroyed here
```

Comment: It seems the range for loop for the iterator caused the trouble. I was informed that the range for loop may crash due to the invalid iterator after erase method is called. I will further work on that asap. Plus, I noticed the side effect exactly as you've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply!

Comment: Of course. Pardon me for the delay, for I was creating a example to show the effect, and I came up with another problem. Thanks again!